Why is There a Switch in Grammar in Sh'ma?
The Sh'ma begins with Dvarim 6:4:

:שְׁמַ֖ע יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל ה׳ אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ ה׳ | אֶחָֽד
Hear, O Israel: The Lord is our God; the Lord is one.

Moshe speaks to the nation in the imperative/command form - "Hear"! This form is used to issue a command in the second person — that is, the command is directed at the person being spoken to.
But then the next verse immediately switches grammatical form:

וְאָ֣הַבְתָּ֔ אֵ֖ת ה׳ אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ בְּכָל־לְבָֽבְךָ֥
וּבְכָל־נַפְשְׁך וּבְכָל־מְאֹדֶֽךָ:
And you shall love the Lord, your God, with all your heart and with
all your soul, and with all your means.

Moshe now tells the nation to love God, but it is in the sequential perfect form. The sequential perfect form, true to its name, discusses a sequence of events. Here it can carry the same meaning as the verb before it - command form. Such as in לֵ֤ךְ וְאָֽמַרְתָּ֙ אֶל־עַבְדִּ֣י אֶל־דָּוִ֔ד/Go and say to my servant David (Samuel 2 7:5). And so is this a normal example of Hebrew Grammar (שמע and ואהבת are both commands) or is something else going on here?
Is the fact that the verses discuss different mitzvot - the Mitzva of God's Oneness v. the Mitzva of loving God - a clue?

Moshe is saying to us, "Hashem is our God, love Him with all your heart"

Isn’t it simply "Listen, y'all, Israel, you shall love the Lord, your God, with all your heart and with all your soul, and with all your means"? I don't see any change in person.

How else should he have said it

It could have said אהוב את ה׳ אלקיך

Yes I believe your suggestion is correct - the switch in grammar has to do with the context of each statement. Let’s break it down:
The first statement that Hashem is our Gd and He is one is stated as a fact. No room to argue or to need to comprehend anything, it just is
Whereas the next verse which commands us to love Gd, even though it’s a commandment and we must do it, you cannot force someone to love something unless they do. Therefore the statement could not have been in the command form because it is something which requires each individual to think about and contemplate to reach this level of love. It’s not something black and white like knowing that Gd is one and can therefore be commanded. This is about emotions and therefore must come from a place of self desire and cannot be commanded upon.
My proof from this comes from Sefer Hamitzvot positive commandments 1, 2 and 3. It is evident from his wording that knowing that Gd exists and that He is one is just a fact that was commanded to us without room for us to think and comprehend. Whereas loving Gd he mentions how we need to contemplate and bring ourselves to understanding etc proving that it’s not something that can be commanded and therefore explains the change in grammar in the verse

Source is where?

According to Sefer haChinuch mitzvah 420, the first passuk is acceptance of kingship for the entire Jewish nation, while the rest of the verses speak of other important individual mitzvos listed elsewhere in the Sefer. There are also different halachic requirements to the 1st verse (Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim, 61:5-7, Ram"a and Mishna Berura there. For example, one cannot walk when reciting the first verse as a result.
